Inequality Involving Ratio of Harmonic Numbers

Does there exists a constant $d$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $k$-tuples of distinct primes primes $p_1, \ldots, p_k \le n^{1/\log \log n}$, with $k\ge 1$, $$\frac{1}{p_1 \cdots p_k} - \frac{H_{ \lfloor \frac{n}{p_1 \cdots p_k} \rfloor}}{p_1 \cdots p_k H_{n}} \le d/n,$$ where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number $\sum_{i=1}^{n}1/i?$

I tried using the asymptotic $H_n = \log n + \gamma$ to replace the $H$'s with logs. For large enough $d$, the inequality seems to hold (based on Wolfram), but I want to see if $d$ can be chosen independently of $n$ and $p$.

No.  Let $k=1$ and let $n$ become large.  Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_n &=& \log n + \gamma + o(1) \qquad \rm and \\
H_{\lfloor n/p_1 \rfloor} &=& \log n - \log p_1 + \gamma + o(1), \qquad \rm so\\
\frac 1{p_1} - \frac{H_{ \lfloor n/p_1 \rfloor}}{p_1  H_{n}}
&=& \frac{\log p_1 + o(1)}{{p_1} (\log n + \gamma + o(1))} \\
&\ge& \frac{\log 2 + o(1)}{ n^{1/\log log n}(\log n + \gamma + o(1))},
\end{eqnarray*}
and this last quantity obviously can't be bounded above by $d/n$ for any constant $d$.
